# return value after meeting two condition

Tags: excel

Can some one help me with the IF Formula. I need an IF formula that will return value of "Open" or "Closed" by evaluating the condition where if I have a cell as below. I need the B3 to be automatically provide status whether open or close after checking Cell A1 if got data and if CellE1 got data then it should return Closed in cell B1 else if the Cell A2 got data but the cell E2 got no data it should return value "Open" in B2.

I tried something like this but didn't work:

`=IF(AND(A2,E2=">0"),"Open",IF(AND(A2,E2"<0"),"Closed"))`

No  Case  Status    Date Created  Date Closed
1   3095    Open    03-Dec-14       03-Dec-14
2   3096    Open    02-Dec-14
3   3097    Open    03-Dec-14      04-Dec-14
4   3098    Open    03-Dec-14      05-Dec-14
5   3099    Open    03-Dec-14

Comment: you're chart doesn't exactly make sense, but if a cell doesn't receive data are they going to be empty or will they say something specific?

Comment: hi sorry if my chart doesn't make sense, but yes if the cell is empty then it should not say anyting just return "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, after all the edits, your data looks like this:

[image: User Data]

At this stage all the Opens in column C had been entered as values so I tried to copy your formula:

`=IF(AND(A2,E2=">0"),"Open",IF(AND(A2,E2"<0"),"Closed"))`

directly into the formula bar with C2 selected and, when I pressed Enter, got this message:

[image: Error message on formula paste]

so did as suggested by clicking Insert Function on the Formulas which led to this:

[image: Function Arguments]

Editing out the double quotes so that `E2",0"` became `E2<0` which corrected the error but the result is not what you are looking for

[image: Function arguments corrected]

The formula evaluates to `FALSE` which is clearly not what is expected.

Using the Evaluate Formula tool on Formulas tab I found that `E2=">0"` evaluates to `FALSE` because it's comparing the date value against the string `>0`.

It then goes on to evealuate the FALSE condition of the IF function (i.e. `IF(AND(A2,E2<0),"Closed")`. There are a couple of issues with this

1. E2 is a date and therefore **always >0**
2. There is no return specified if `AND(A2,E2<0)` evaluates to `FALSE` which in this case it does. If no return is specified, the IF function just returns `FALSE`

So that's why cell C2 is displaying `FALSE`

If I understand correctly you want Status to be

1. Blank if A2 is blank
2. "Open" if A2 is not blank AND E2 is blank
3. "Closed" if A2 is not blank AND E2 is a date in the format "dd-mmm-yy"

We can test for blank cells using `=NOT(ISBLANK(A2))` or `A2<>""`

Condition 2 can be tested using `ISBLANK(E2)`

Excel doesn't have an ISDATE function so for condition 3 we need to use the obscure `CELL("format",reference)` function

There are a couple of solutions depending on which test you want to use for blank cells:

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),
    IF(ISBLANK(E2),"Open",
    IF(CELL("format",E2)="D1","Closed","Date Closed isn't a date")),"")`

Or

`=IF(A2<>"",
    IF(E2<>"",
      IF(CELL("format",E2)="D1","Closed","Date Closed is not a date"),
    "Open"),"")`

Comment: Dear Mr mark, need a bit more explanation on the formula:-IF(CELL("format",E2)="D1","Closed","Date Closed isn't a date")),"") what will the condition above do? sorry i  not able to get it....

Comment: I don't know what else to add...they either work or they don't.  Try pasting them into your sheet and let me know if they do or don't.

Comment: I'm glad it is now working for you. I will be happy if you could mark the answer as "Accepted" though.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again but may I know if the same formula would work if I want it to check for specific month as my data have dates.

Answer (score -1):

your syntax is slightly wrong, this should work: `=IF(AND(A2>0,E2>0),"Open",IF(AND(A2<0,E2<0),"Closed"))`